# Making MySQL inserts from multiple dynamic HTML tables generated in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, include

I am working with a PHP file that generates many dynamic HTML tables using an included PHP library. This is a sample of the HTML output (I have listed only two tables and reduced their rows to 5 and 7 respectively) http://pastebin.com/PCwXyAjd

I'm trying to fetch the data from the HTML table into a MySQL database. I do not have access to view-source or edit that included PHP library so I cant make it write straight into MySQL when creating the HTML table.

Please how can I make my PHP file write this generated HTML data into MySQL? Thanks.

Comment: Two questions: 1. How do you access the library output? 2. What part of HTML shown do you want to store in MySQL?

Comment: 1. I use <?php require_once("../includes/userdata.php"); $today = date("Ymd"); $data = new Userdata($today); echo $data; ?> but I do not have access to edit the physical file userdata.php

Comment: 2. I need to store the id (auto-incremented), Table name, and their data e.g. a sample row is "1", "Table 1", "Lee", "15.46", "-20.5", "", "11.25" under fields id, tablename, name, amount, appraisal, estimate, quantity. (each entry is unique to a table) Thanks!

Comment: Surely `userdata.php` is getting the data from a database itself? Are you sure you can't just connect to that? It seems very backwards to parse HTML to insert data which came from one database into another database.

Comment: Oh thanks thirtydot but I dont seem to have a choice. Because userdata is not fetching from a database. It polls by date and parses the information from many Microsoft Excel worksheets - and I am not privy to them either. A major problem is: multiple tables and very many records per table so it can't be done manually.

Comment: "parses the information from many Microsoft Excel worksheets" - I now agree that parsing the generated HTML is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It's a PHP Simple HTML DOM parser. I am investigating it now and I think it should do the trick - it will parse the HTML contents and then I can post into MySQL - will keep you posted.